# How to register touch in didMoveToView (Swift, SpriteKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a repeating action in my very first scene which I want to stop as soon as the user touches the screen for the very first time. Is it possible to detect a touch in `didMoveToView`? I cannot use `touchesBegan` as this is a special case for the very first touch only, and I don't want it repeating for every touch.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    triangle.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2)
    self.addChild(triangle)
    triangle.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateAction))
    //->This is where I need to detect a touch
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During `didMoveToView` -- especially when that is first being called when you app launches -- there can't yet be a current touch event because you're not running in response to the main event loop. If you want to handle a touch, `touchesBegan` is the place to do that.

If you want to do something only on the first touch event you receive, all you need to do is track whether a touch event is the first. For example:

```
var touchedBefore = false
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if !touchedBefore {
        touchedBefore = true
        // do your first-touch business
    } else {
        // do your touch handling for other times
    }
}
```